# Error in using C SDK in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dll, sdk

I'm trying to use a SDK with python. 
I have multiple dll files in the SPK. 
My script:

```
import ctypes    
import os

malib = ctypes.WinDLL(os.path.join('D:\Downloads\Aura API\sdk\AURA_SDK.dll'))    
print(malib.GetClaymoreKeyboardLedCount(1)) #function in the dll
```

I get the error :

> WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000005

I can use some of the functions normaly but for others I get this issue. Also there are different dll's in the SDK and I think the problem could come from the communication between these dll (I only open one of these dll in the script) also because function not working seem to be using the other dll or/and communication with the computer.

Thanks if you got advices

Comment: By the way, this is a perfectly good question as a separate followup to your previous question—but you should mention somewhere that it’s a followup, with a link. Otherwise, people may vaguely remember seeing your previous question yesterday and assume this is a duplicate rather than a new question, and you may get downvotes or close votes that you don’t deserve.

Comment: That being said, there’s a good chance this _is_ a duplicate of someone else’s question that I haven’t found yet, so it may end up getting closed anyway—but in that case it’ll get closed with a link to an answer that works for you and explains the issue, which is even better than getting an answer.

Comment: I'm sorry starting in here thank you (Sure someone gives me a post I didn't find with the awnser it is as much helping)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the [`argtypes` and `restype`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes) for the functions you're calling.

This means that, instead of knowing what C types to convert your arguments to, `ctypes` has to guess based on the Python types you pass it. If it guesses wrong, you will either pass garbage, or, worse, corrupt the stack, leading to an access violation.

For example, imagine this C function:

```
void func(int64_t n, char *s);
```

If you do this:

```
lib = # however you load the library
lib.func(2, 'abc')
```

… then `ctypes`, it will convert that `2` to a 32-bit int, not a 64-bit one. If you're using a 32-bit Python and DLL, that means `n` will get the `2` and the pointer to `'abc'` crammed into one meaningless number, and `s` will be an uninitialized pointer to some arbitrary location in memory that, if your lucky, won't be mapped to anything and will raise an access violation.

But if you first do this:

```
lib = # however you load the library
lib.func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int64, ctypes.c_char_p]
lib.func.restype = None
lib.func(2, 'abc')
```

… then `ctypes` will convert the 2 to a 64-bit int, so `n` will get `2` and `s` will get `'abc'` and everyone will be happy.

Comment: You must be right, thank you. I thought controlling C throught Python would be easier, I will just give up, I know nothing about C and it seems that I can't use functions of this SDK without this knowledge

Comment: @R.Reus You may want to try using `cffi` instead of `ctypes`. The learning curve for really trivial stuff is a bit higher, but for medium-complexity stuff like this it's often easier. Or, swig may be able to auto-generate the bindings for you, but if it runs into any problems, dealing with them requires knowing _both_ C and swig's own funky mini-language, so…